# Fine-tune a pre-trained model

Tags: huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, pre-trained-model

I am new to transformer based models. I am trying to fine-tune the following model (https://huggingface.co/Chramer/remote-sensing-distilbert-cased) on my dataset. The code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykj0y.png)

and I got the following error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlvxC.png)

I will be thankful if anyone could help.

The preprocessing steps I followed:

```
input_ids_t = []
attention_masks_t = []


for sent in df_train['text_a']:
encoded_dict = tokenizer.encode_plus(
                    sent,                      
                    add_special_tokens = True, 
                    max_length = 128,           
                    pad_to_max_length = True,
                    return_attention_mask = True,  
                    return_tensors = 'tf',     
               )

    
input_ids_t.append(encoded_dict['input_ids'])

attention_masks_t.append(encoded_dict['attention_mask'])

# Convert the lists into tensors.
input_ids_t = tf.concat(input_ids_t, axis=0)
attention_masks_t = tf.concat(attention_masks_t, axis=0)
labels_t = np.asarray(df_train['label'])
```

and i did the same for testing data. Then:

```
 train_data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((input_ids_t,attention_masks_t,labels_t))
```

and the same for testing data

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are feeding the `transformer_model` 1 input instead of 3. Try removing the square brackets around `transformer_model([input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids])[0]` so that it reads `transformer_model(input_ids, input_mask, segment_ids)[0]`. That way, the function will have 3 arguments and not just 1.

Comment: Also, for future reference, it is usually more helpful to copy-paste the error as a code block instead of screenshooting a picture. This will also help other people who run into the same error and search for answers using the error text

Comment: Thank Adel, I did remove square brackets but still I got the same error